# Reproducing the option to force close

Tags: android, forceclose

In android there is option in
Settings->application->your app-> force close

Does anyone know how does it work programmatically?
I tried a lot of things to close my app and those not working properly.

And those shutting down app completely with all threads/services.

Anyway I need something what close my app with threads sevices and everything.

```
 public void turnOffApp() {
    try {
        for (IThreadController thread : Objects.threadList) {
            thread.stopThread();
        }
        Log.d(Objects.context.getString(R.string.complete), Objects.context.getString(R.string.turningOffThreads));
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(Objects.context.getString(R.string.error), Objects.context.getString(R.string.throwErrorWhileStoppingThreads), e);
    }
}
```

Objects.threadList is a globalObject where i store all my created threads.
Btw is fire also when app closeing or crashes and then it's work corectly but i want to have it also in button and here isn't work so well

Comment: So, you want to programmatically CRASH your app, and make your users go nuts? Simply generate a NPE.

Comment: Not Crash turn off onClick cause i need to close all threads/services on close what u meen by generate NPE
Btw why i get -2?

Comment: Force close sends a unix signal. You can achieve the same effect by sending yourself a signal, or by calling `System.exit(1);`. Any number will do, it doesn't have to be 1.

Comment: By the way, the use of `System.exit()` is strongly discouraged.

Comment: System.exit() only restart my app don't close it

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to kill application, though you can achieve this by let say on pressing a button you load First activity and clear all other activities in stack. Now you are left with one activity to deal with, to finish that you can do as following :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

The above code removes all activities from stack except for FirstActivity. To finish the FirstActivity enter the below code in Firstactivity's oncreate

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("EXIT",false)) {
finish();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: that not closeing my app leaveing all threads and service closing only last activity but beside activity i have other features

Comment: you can always choose to stop your background services before executing above code, also interrupt and destroy threads in case Activity/Fragment onDestroy() method is called.

Comment: if i use finish as close method nothing happense if i use System.exit(0); it restart KillProces also dosn't work i tryed couple more ways but nothing seems to work 
BTW i killing my threads before use close function

Comment: share your code where you are using finish() method.

Comment: edited at current is that but that don't work properly